# How to format a specific dataframe cell to be red if its value is different from zero?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, conditional-formatting, pandas-styles

I have a dataframe that calculates 3 things and outputs the results. One row represents the number of records on file, the second row represents the number of records where a specific column has null values (number of missing IDs), and the third row also represents the number of records where a specific column has null values (number of missing names).

I want to conditionally format certain cells to be red if they are != 0.

See below for my dataframe contents and more context for what I want to conditionally turn red:

```py
def record_count():
    with open('filename.csv', encoding='utf8') as file:
        record_number = len(list(file))
        print("Number of records on file:", record_number)
        return record_number

def id_check():
    df = pd.read_csv('filename.csv', low_memory=False)
    missing_id = df["id"].isna().sum()
    print("Number of users missing an id:", missing_id)
    return missing_id

def name_check():
    df = pd.read_csv('filename.csv', low_memory=False)
    missing_name = derivs["name"].isna().sum()
    print("Number of users missing a name:", missing_name)
    return missing_name

checks_table = {
    'Check' : ['Record Check', 'ID Check', 'Name Check'],
    'Summary' : ['Number of records on file','Number of records missing an ID', 'Number of users missing a name'],
    'Findings' : [record_count(), id_check(), name_check()]
}

df_checks = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(checks_table)
df_checks.head()
```

I am trying to format my `checks_table` dataframe so that:

- any cell where the Check = ID Check and the Findings id_check() != 0 then cell value = red
- or where Check = Name check and Findings name_check() != 0 then cell value = red

Everything else can default to black.

Answer (score 0):

With the following toy dataframe (I'm guessing here what yours looks like):

```py
# In a Jupyter notebook

checks_table = {
    "Check": ["Record Check", "ID Check", "Name Check"],
    "Summary": [
        "Number of records on file",
        "Number of records missing an ID",
        "Number of users missing a name",
    ],
    "Findings": [50, 10, 7],
}

df_checks = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(checks_table)
df_checks
```

[image]

Here is one way to do it by defining a helper function:

```py
def red_if_not_zero(s, **kwargs):
    return ["color: red" if v != 0 else "" for v in df_checks.loc[[1, 2], "Findings"]]
```

Then, running the following line in a Jupyter notebook cell:

```py
df_checks.style.apply(red_if_not_zero, subset=([1, 2], "Findings"))
```

Outputs:

[image]